# PageSpeed Insights no longer working on my PC. (https://pagespeed.web.dev/) / Any Solutions?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insights (https://pagespeed.web.dev/) is no longer working on my PC. It just spins. I've tried using multiple different URL's to analyze. I've tried it in Incognito. I've cleared cache. I've reinstalled Chrome. I've even tried it with the Edge Browser.

This seems to correspond to the new Pagespeed Insights Release. I've never had a problem with this until recently. This has always worked before.

I don't know if it's a cookie issue, or the new PageSpeed Insights release, maybe a new firewall issue that cropped up. Or, does it now require a KEY or something? Or, could my IP have gotten blocked by Google for this?

Note: I can run Lighthouse from Inspect. That works. But not https://pagespeed.web.dev/

Windows - Chrome is up to date Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I'm baffled. It's probably something obvious but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas out there?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Yes same here. .

Answer (score 0):

For us, the lighthouse report in Chrome dev tools is not working behind a VPN. It was working earlier. Not sure what is the issue.

We were looking to test new page templates on the dev environment. Unfortunately, the PSI is not warming on staging on a VPN

Comment: Actually, Lighthouse is working fine. but https://pagespeed.web.dev/ sometimes saying "Running performance analysis" :(

Comment: But, compare than previous tool is great. I think there is some issue on Pagespeed.web.dev